# store three bits value to unsigned char array

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to take a given 3 bits value and store the 3 bits value to unsigned char array[3], the following is my example, the array value display in binary to easy understand, does anyone know what would be the better way to achieve this function?

For example:

```
unsigned char array[3] = {0};

function_store_3bits_value(3);
array[0] = 011 000 00b
array[1] = 0 000 000 0b;
array[2] = 00 000 000b;

function_store_3bits_value(7);
array[0] = 011 111 00b
array[1] = 0 000 000 0b;
array[2] = 00 000 000b;

function_store_3bits_value(5);
array[0] = 011 111 10b
array[1] = 1 000 000 0b;
array[2] = 00 000 000b;

function_store_3bits_value(2);
array[0] = 011 111 10b
array[1] = 1 010 000 0b;
array[2] = 00 000 000b;

function_store_3bits_value(1);
array[0] = 011 111 10b
array[1] = 1 010 001 0b;
array[2] = 00 000 000b;

function_store_3bits_value(6);
array[0] = 011 111 10b
array[1] = 1 010 001 1b;
array[2] = 10 000 000b;

function_store_3bits_value(7);
array[0] = 011 111 10b
array[1] = 1 010 001 1b;
array[2] = 10 111 000b;
```

Comment: "better way" implies that you have already implemented a version of this function – please post it.

Comment: Unless you have very tight memory usage requirements, I wouldn't bother with using up all the bits. I would just put one or two three bit values in single char (maybe 5 three bit values in wchar so you only waste 1 bit for padding). That way you don't have to bother with breaking the values between multiple bytes.

Comment: Note also that if you pack this 3-byte array with any other object, that object will probably be padded to fit it's needed alignment, wasting at least 1 more byte. Of course, if these 3 bytes form part of a larger array of 3bit counters, then that is less of an issue.

Comment: If you really want to pack a number of small counts into an integer, have a look at the old c bit field structure feature. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field

Comment: C or C++, please make up your mind, answers will be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started. Various improvements are possible—this is not “the better way.”

```
unsigned char array[3] = {0};
unsigned int NextBit = 0;   //  Position where the next bit will be written.


#include <limits.h> //  To define CHAR_BIT.


//  Store one bit in the array.
static void StoreOneBit(unsigned x)
{
    //  Limit x to one bit.
    x &= 1;

    //  Calculate which array element the next bit is in.
    unsigned i = NextBit / CHAR_BIT;

    //  Calculate which column the next bit is in.
    unsigned j = CHAR_BIT - (NextBit % CHAR_BIT) - 1;

    //  OR the new bit into the array.  (This will not turn off previous bits.)
    array[i] |= x << j;

    //  Increment position for the next bit.
    ++NextBit;
}


//  Store three bits in the array.
static void function_store_3bits_value(int x)
{
    //  Use unsigned for safety.
    unsigned u = x;

    //  Store each of the three bits.
    StoreOneBit(u>>2);
    StoreOneBit(u>>1);
    StoreOneBit(u>>0);
}


#include <stdio.h>


//  Store three bits and show the result.
static void Do(int x)
{
    function_store_3bits_value(x);
    printf("Stored %d.  Array = %#x, %#x, %#x.\n",
        x, array[0], array[1], array[2]);
}


int main(void)
{
    Do(3);
    Do(7);
    Do(5);
    Do(2);
    Do(1);
    Do(6);
    Do(7);
}
```